# Shared UI function between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have some UI related function such as show warning popup, present a activity indicator in middle of screen, or show a Animate a UIView on screen with a custom message.
I want to use then in multiple viewControllers (VC1, and VC2 in this case) so I dont repeat myself.
Initially, I have the following code that works with both VCs inherit from a BaseVC that takes cares of those functions. 
VC1 is a UIViewController with tablelView embedded, VC2 is a UIViewController with collectionView embedded.

```
class VC1: BaseVC {
    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        activityIndicatorBegin()
    }

    func btnPressed() {
        activityIndicatorEnd()
    }
}

class VC2: BaseVC {
    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        activityIndicatorBegin()
    }

    func btnPressed() {
        activityIndicatorEnd()
    }
}

class BaseVC: UIViewController {

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    var isCustomViewOnScreen = false

    func activityIndicatorBegin() {
        if activityIndicator.isAnimating() == false {
            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,20,20))
            activityIndicator.center = view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
            activityIndicator.color = UIColor.blackColor()
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }
    }

    func activityIndicatorEnd() {
        if activityIndicator.isAnimating() == true {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func animateACustomViewOnScreen() {
        if isCustomViewOnScreen == false {
            // Some animation code 
        }
    }

    func removeCustomView() {
        if isCustomViewOnScreen == true {
            // Some removal code
        }
    }
}
```

However, due to some reasons, I decide to make VC1 straight for UITableViewController and VC2 from UICollectionViewController instead.
This means that they no longer can inehrit from this BaseVC that is of class UIViewController.
How could I make it so that both VC can still reach those functions?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is [`Protocol Extensions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521). You define `BaseVC` as a protocol and then extend that by adding the shared logic that will be used throughout classes implementing it:

*(BaseVC is renamed as `ActivityIndicatorDisplaying` in the below example.)*

```
protocol ActivityIndicatorDisplaying {

  var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView { get set }
  var showsCustomView: Bool { get }

  func showActivityIndicator()
  func dismissActivityIndicator()
}

extension ActivityIndicatorDisplaying where Self: UIViewController {

  func showActivityIndicator() {
    if activityIndicator.isAnimating() { return }

    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.width / 2, view.bounds.height / 2)
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
    activityIndicator.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
  }

  func dismissActivityIndicator() {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  func animateACustomViewOnScreen() {
    if !showsCustomView {
      // Some animation code
    }
  }

  func removeCustomView() {
    if showsCustomView {
      // Some removal code
    }
  }
}

class VC1: UITableViewController, ActivityIndicatorDisplaying {

  var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
  var showsCustomView: Bool = false

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    showActivityIndicator()
  }

  func btnPressed() {
    dismissActivityIndicator()
  }
}

class VC2: UICollectionViewController, ActivityIndicatorDisplaying {

  var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
  var showsCustomView: Bool = true

  ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer , but `extension ActivityIndicatorDisplaying where Self: UIViewController` what if you are showing a `UIView` still works ?

Comment: No it doesn't work as `.addSubview` is called on view controller's `.view` property. If you want it to work with both UIView and UIViewController then you should remove `where Self: UIViewController` and define another property in the protocol like: `var view: UIView { get }`

Comment: Any reason why this solution have more vote then the one below from Jason? His way does not introduce extra flags in all the VCs

Answer (score 0):

Why not subclass the UIActivityViewController itself?
It would be more logical and cleaner.

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    var customActivityIndicatorView: CustomActivityIndicatorView? = nil

    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let view = view {
            customActivityIndicatorView = CustomActivityIndicatorView(parentView: view)
        }
    }

    func btnPressed() {
        customActivityIndicatorView?.end()
    }
}

class VC2: UITableViewController {
    var customActivityIndicatorView: CustomActivityIndicatorView? = nil

    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let view = view {
            customActivityIndicatorView = CustomActivityIndicatorView(parentView: view)
        }
    }

    func btnPressed() {
        customActivityIndicatorView?.end()
    }
}

class CustomActivityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView {
    var isCustomViewOnScreen = false

    convenience init?(parentView: UIView) {
        if isAnimating == false {
            self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            center = parentView.center
            hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
            color = UIColor.black
            parentView.addSubview(self)
            startAnimating()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func end() {
        if isAnimating == true {
            stopAnimating()
            removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func animateACustomViewOnScreen() {
        if isCustomViewOnScreen == false {
            // Some animation code
        }
    }

    func removeCustomView() {
        if isCustomViewOnScreen == true {
            // Some removal code
        }
    }
}
```